# Scrapy loop through Subpages and API

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

My Scraper is behaving not correctly. The page has multiple entries on the page and the scraper should klick on every entry and get the information from the detailed page and then go on to the next entry. Then change the page number when all entries are finished. Additionally, there are some information retrieved from an API call during this process. But somehow the coding does not go to the subpage every time and I have the feeling the implementation of response is not correct. Its just staying in the first "parse" loop and sometimes goes to "parse_property" and sometimes to "get_additional_price".

Some importanc code snippets:

```
def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(self.url)


def parse(self, response):
   ...
yield response.follow(url=item['url'], callback=self.parse_property, meta={'item': item})
...
yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Subpage data:

```
def parse_property(self, response):
...
yield response.follow(url=url, callback=self.get_addition_price, meta={'item': item})
```

API Data:

```
def get_addition_price(self, response):
...
yield item
```

Is this the correct way?

Comment: Please provide full code if you can and also the website you are trying to access.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve